# Execute Oracle Stored Proc using .Net

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I created a package :

```
create or replace PACKAGE merc
AS 
 TYPE resultcurtyp is REF CURSOR;
END merc;
```

And then a stored proc:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE merc_results
(
 testP IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
 CURSOR_ IN OUT merc.resultcurtyp

) AS 
BEGIN
    OPEN CURSOR_ FOR
    SELECT /*csv*/
    FR.*
    FROM DS.table1 FR 
    INNER JOIN DS.price PN ON PN.OBJECTID = FR.SOURCEID 
    WHERE FR.NAME = testP   
END merc_results;
```

While calling the Stored proc form .Net code  gives me :

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:
PLS-00222: no function with name 'merc' exists in this scope
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Do I need to create a **package**, call stored from that and then call the package from .Net ? I am calling the stored proc directly from code right now.
I Haven't worked with oracle db before.

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to declare your own weakly typed cursor rather than just declaring `cursor_` of type `sys_refcursor`?  Do you really want the `cursor_` parameter to be `IN OUT` rather than just `OUT`?  And why are you using the `/*csv*/` hint in a stored procedure-- that's just a SQL Developer directive.  You've tagged this for SQL Developer which is makes me suspect that the `csv` hint is supposed to do something functional?

Comment: Well, you don't show the C# calling code.

Comment: @JustinCave, he's not really using the csv hint, he's missing the plus, `/*+csv*/` so it's just a comment.

Comment: Looks like you either using package as function or your package is in different schema than the one you connected to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c#:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("yourshema.merc.merc_results", Connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("testP", testP);
cmd.Parameters.Add("CURSOR_", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
return ds;
```

Oracle Package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE merc
IS
    TYPE resultcurtyp IS REF CURSOR;
    PROCEDURE merc_results(
        testP IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
        CURSOR_ OUT resultcurtyp );
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY merc
IS
  PROCEDURE merc_results(
    testP IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    CURSOR_ OUT resultcurtyp )
  AS
  BEGIN
   OPEN CURSOR_ FOR SELECT
    FR.* FROM DS.table1 FR INNER JOIN DS.price PN ON PN.OBJECTID = FR.SOURCEID WHERE FR.NAME = testP;
  END merc_results;
END merc;
/
```